# Disproving the statement A×B⊆C×D if and only if A⊆C and B⊆D

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, cross-product

I know that a counterexample can disprove this statement
I tried a lot to disprove it without using a counterexample
If A⊆C and B⊆D
let (x,y)∈ (A×B)
⇒x∈A and  y∈B
⇒x∈C and  y∈D(from the assumption)
⇒A×B⊆C×D
Similarly, let (A×B)⊆(C×D)
let  (x,y)∈(A×B)
⇒  (x,y)∈(C×D)(from the assumption)
i.e., x∈A and y∈B  ⇒  x∈C and y∈D
⇒ A⊆C and B⊆D
But this proves the statement instead of disproving it
I have just begun discrete maths, and I can't figure out where I am going wrong. It would be extremely helpful if someone could tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: What happens if we consider $A = \left\lbrace 1 \right\rbrace = D$, $B = C = \emptyset$? Looking at this example do you see where the problem in your proof is?

Comment: The statement is true if all the sets are assumed nonempty.

Comment: I think that the problem is in the 2nd part. That subset condition doesn't necessarily need to be satisfied if empty sets are involved. Am I right?

Comment: Either $A$ or $B$ must be empty.